# Failure to eager load scoped has_many through association with join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a many-to-many relationship between accounts and categories using a join table, account_category. Setting up the default relationship in the `Account` class is easy:

```
has_many :account_category  
has_many :categories, :through => :account_category
```

what I can't figure out is how to properly scope additional custom `has_many`s on categories.

```
has_many :foobar_categories,
         -> { where type: "foobar" },
         through: :account_category,
         source: :category
```

This results in a failure to eager load foobar_categories:

```
# This is a N + 1 query 
Account.includes(:foobar_categories).all.each do
  # do stuff with account.foobar_categories
end
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Is it really not possible to eager load scoped has_many through associations?

EDIT: Two responses so far suggest using a scope on Category. I do not believe a scope on Category is correct for two reasons:

1. In the "Eager loading of associations" section [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) it shows that this *should* be possible with a scoped association.
2. How would you eager load the scope of an association even if you were to use a scope?

EDIT 2: I finally found the source of the issue . . method calls hidden in the class with the same name as my associations that were overriding the associations. Apologies for my oversite, and thanks to those who took the time to answer. I'm flagging this post for deletion since the fault lies in our code instead of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Define the scope on the model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.foobar
    where("categories.name = 'foobar'")
  end
end
```

Include :categories and merge the scope:

```
Account.includes(:categories).merge(Category.foobar).each do |a|
  a.categories.each do |c|
     puts c.created_at
  end
end
```

Comment: This disregards the need for the associations themselves. I don't want all foobar_categories, I want all the foobar_categories for a specific account, all the foobar2_categories for a specific account, etc.

Comment: Move the scope to the Category then, and call like `account.categories.foobar` (see edit to answer)

Comment: How would you eager load the scope? Wouldn't this still result in calls to the db every time you called account.categories.foobar? Also, I think it is better practice to make such a scope as was suggested by jamesy829 over the metaprogramming of `define_singleton_method`

Comment: This will make 1 query to get the `categories` for each account.  Eager load them in advance of this if you don't want that.  `Account.all.includes(:categories).each do account.categories.foobar end`.  You're going to end up writing the exact same scope 4 times; this is one of the main DRY benefits of metaprogramming.

Comment: That still results in an N + 1 query . . `Account.all.includes(:categories).each { |account| account.categories.foobar_categories }` results in an additional DB call for every single account since the DB has to make a new call to figure out what the scope is. Includes only works on the initial call to categories, but the where clause in the scope means rails needs an additional DB call. EDIT: Just to be explicit: I tested this to be certain it was the case.

Comment: One last attempt.  See edit.  Enjoy.

Comment: I tossed you an upvote for the creative solution, although I am closing this post as per EDIT 2 in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a scope instead of custom association.

scope :foobar_categories -> { includes(:categories).where(name: 'foobar') }

Comment: This doesn't quite work when you have multiple custom categories that you want to eager load. In my case, there are actually 4 similar custom associations I need to eager load and later access.

Comment: also, I don't think you can eager load the scope of an association. How would you eager load this from a call to Account.all such that iterating over the collection would not result in additional calls to the DB whenever you want to access the foobar_categories for an account?